# Getting NoMethodError: undefined method `to_datetime' for true:TrueClass: when INSERT into Mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using: 
Ruby version: 2.3.1p112
Rails version: 4.0.1 with WEBrick
Mysql version: 5.7.13 Homebrew

Here is my controller code:

```
class AutomationTestsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_automation_test, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def create
  params_all=params[:automation_test]
  params_exclude_optional=params_all.except(:parameter10)
  unless params_exclude_optional.values.include?""
    @automation_test = AutomationTest.new(automation_test_params)

  respond_to do |format|
      if @automation_test.save
```

...

at the bottom of my controller I have this:

```
private
def set_automation_test
  @automation_test = AutomationTest.find(params[:id])
end

def automation_test_params
  params.require(:automation_test).permit(:Project, :ProjectType, :Status, :parameter1, :parameter2, :parameter3, :parameter4, :parameter4, :parameter5, :parameter6, :parameter7, :parameter8, :parameter9, :parameter10)
end
```

Here is the code from my schema.rb:

```
create_table "automation_tests", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "Project"
  t.string   "ProjectType"
  t.string   "Status"
  t.string   "parameter1"
  t.string   "parameter2"
  t.string   "parameter3"
  t.string   "parameter4"
  t.string   "parameter5"
  t.string   "parameter6"
  t.string   "parameter7"
  t.string   "parameter8"
  t.string   "parameter9"
  t.string   "parameter10"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I added this to be able to run my migration:  config/initializers/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb

```
activeSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter
 NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
end
end
```

I realize the save method is deprecated, but I thought it should still work, no?

server output:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_datetime' for true:TrueClass: INSERT INTO `automation_tests` (`Param1`, ...)
```

Here is Rails attempting the INSERT:
SQL (4.3ms)  INSERT INTO `automation_tests` (`Project`, `ProjectType`, `Status`, `created_at`, `parameter1`, `parameter10`, `parameter3`, `parameter4`, `parameter5`, `parameter6`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["Project", "NissanMipRestAutomation"], ["ProjectType", "mipresttestautomation"], ["Status", "READY"], ["created_at", Tue, 13 Sep 2016 14:24:33 PDT -07:00], ["parameter1", "full-suite"], ["parameter10", ""], ["parameter3", "Environment=Test"], ["parameter4", "Brand=Nissan"], ["parameter5", "Category=NNA"], ["parameter6", "Country=US"], ["updated_at", Tue, 13 Sep 2016 14:24:33 PDT -07:00]]

I see rails is also creating a "date" to inject into the updated_at and created_at columns: ["updated_at", Tue, 13 Sep 2016 14:24:33 PDT -07:00], but I can't image this is problematic.

If anyone has ideas about what is causing this, I would appreciate your help.  Thanks.

---

I finally figured this out!  I was using a 'mysql' gem, and it was having a hard time with mysql 5.7.13.
I switched to using gem mysql2 v.0.3.18 and it immediately worked.

Comment: please edit the question with the piece of code, where you use `to_datetime` - it's the place, where you call the method on the wrong object

Comment: So, save isn't depreciated, it is moved to a new module of ActiveRecord.  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save

Comment: Thanks.  That's just it... I have no code that calls to_datetime.  Thus my hypotheses about rails doing it for the default fields created_at and updated_at.

Comment: @RosyRuby but you have a AR model instance in the controller instance variable `@automation_test`, having a look at this model and how you pass the params to it might help. The error message is telling us that rails is trying to cast true to a DateTime Object. So an assumption might be that you are setting a DateTime value on the model to true.

Comment: @AndyGauge, Hi.  I still can't figure this out.  I added the insert Rails is sending to Mysql... could the date format that it sends for the created_at or updated_at fields be problematic?

Comment: Do you have any callbacks in your model? E.g. `before_save`, `after_validation`, etc.

Comment: Someone might not be able to help until we see the whole of your controller and model. We certainly don't know how you pass your params and co.

Comment: @dinjas  Thanks.  I added any part of my controller that deals with the params.  I have no param processing in the model.

Comment: Can you include the `schema.rb`, the part that relates to `AutomationTest`? It would help identify the datetime fields in the table.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: Hi.  Yes, I added my schema.rb portion of this table.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?  Could this be a problem with the versions of Mysql and rails I am using?  I haven't found anything on the interwebs about it.

Comment: The only thing that looks suspect is the datetime rails is trying to inject isn't a mysql format:  Tue, 13 Sep 2016 14:24:33 PDT -07:00

Comment: If datetime format is the problem, how about setting your timezone to UTC? Rails creates update_at and created_at records with Time method with timezone. But in MySQL, time defference(like -07:00) causes errors in save recorods, because MySQL doesn't keep timezone.